# How can I convert Meissel's/Lehmer's formula for prime counting to get sum of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem, prime-gaps

[Legendre's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresFormula.html) can be very easily be generalised as mentioned [here](https://projecteuler.net/action=redirect;post_id=111677) (visible after login) which is like this

${\pi}(v,p)={\pi}(v,p-1)-1.[{\pi}(v/p,p-1)-{\pi}(p-1,p-1)]$

${  \big\downarrow}$

$S(v,p)=S(v,p-1)-p[S(v/p,p-1)-S(p-1,p-1)]$

This is still $O(n^{3/4})$ algorithm

I have been trying to achieve the same with [Lehmer's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LehmersFormula.html)

$\pi(n)=φ(n, a)+\frac{1}{2}(b+a-2)(b-a+1)-\sum_{i=a}^{b}{\pi}(\frac{x}{p_i})-\sum_{i=a+1}^c \sum_{j=i}^{b_{i}}[{\pi}(\frac{x}{p_ip_j})-(j-1)]$

where $b = n^{1/2}, c = \pi(n^{1/3}), a = \pi(n^{1/4}), φ(n,a)-$ **number of integers** in [1;n] such that they are not divisible by any prime among first $a$ primes.

${  \big\downarrow}$

$S(n)=\Phi(n, a)+\frac{1}{2}(\sum b+\sum a-2)(\sum b-\sum a+1)-\sum_{i=a}^{b}p_i{S}(\frac{x}{p_i})-\sum_{i=a+1}^c \sum_{j=i}^{b_{i}}[p_ip_j{S}(\frac{x}{p_ip_j})-\sum(j-1)]$

The above expression works fine till $n=8$; after that it doesn't.
I am not exactly sure what to do with $\frac{1}{2}(b+a-2)(b-a+1)$ It should not be left as is.
Adding $\sum$ may not be the right way to go.

Then I realised
$\frac{1}{2}(b+a-2)(b-a+1)=a+(a+1)+(a+2)+.......for (b-a) terms$

My required sum should be $\sum a+\sum (a+1)+\sum (a+2)+.......for (b-a) terms$ but even that gives an expression $(b-a)[(a^2+ab+b^2)-1]/6$ which is also giving the correct answer for $n \le 8$.

I have successfully transitioned to from $φ(n, a)$ to $\Phi(n, a)$ where $\Phi(n, a)$ - **sum of integers** in [1;n] such that they are not divisible by any prime among the first $a$ primes.

I guess the equivalent expression of $\frac{1}{2}(b+a-2)(b-a+1)$ should be $s'(a)+s'(a+1)+s'(a+2)+.......for (b-a)$

note: $s'(x)$ is the sum of first $x$ primes; $S(x)$ is the sum of all primes up to $x$.

PS: I am not looking for any suggestion of alternate $O(n^{2/3})$ or similar algos.
For that I have already gone through [Fastest Algorithm to Compute the Sum of Primes?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81443/fastest-algorithm-to-compute-the-sum-of-primes) and more similar literature.
As a part of this question I am only looking to generalise the Meissel-Lehmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a "shameless plug" but i did recently "generalize Meissel-Lehmer to count sum of the powers of primes". This was supposed to give an exposition, so it might be of help
https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.15545

Comment: Even after generalizing Meissel-Lehmer I am finding my recursive implementation of Meissel-Lehmer is slower than the Iterative implementation of Legendre's one. Thanks for publishing the code. I dont know  why but very few number theory researchers do.

Comment: Great work. No wonder I was gettiing such terrible performance. I had just plugged in `P2()` ,`P3()` as in definition who in turn calls `F()` back making a mess of mutual recursion. Simplification really helped. I knew fenwik tree would help to optimise further. This paper just seems to be the work that I needed. May I take this opputunity to ask a realted("shameless") question. Can you tell me what algo is [this](http://judge.yosupo.jp/submission/7976) No sieve, no advanced data structure, mere 50 lines of code yet performing way better than meissel-lehmer. Is it LMO or Deleglise-Rivat?

Comment: I have no clue what they are doing with `smalls`, `roughs` and `larges`. It might be efficient way of implementing meissel-lehmer where they are using `larges` for $\phi$ , `roughs` for $P_2$ and `smalls` for $P_3$ as what it seems. I know comments may not be the best place to have such extensive discussion, but I guess my mathoverflow profile is too new to allow chat invitation functionality. I am anyways available at lucy.benjamin1234@gmail.com for more extensive.

Comment: @LucyBenjamin, `smalls` and `larges` are conceptually one array. If $x \le \sqrt{N}$ then the value is found in `smalls[x]`, otherwise in `larges[N/x]`. (Actually it's slightly more complicated because only odd indices are handled, but I hope you get the general idea). I haven't analysed the code to figure out what `roughs` is, but I suspect that this is Meissel-Lehmer implemented non-recursively.

Answer (score 2):

If you consult [Lehmer's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255455259), the terms in question arise from $$P_2(x, a) = \sum_{p_a < p_i \le \frac x{p_i}} \sum_{p_i \le p_j \le \frac x{p_i}} 1 = \sum_{p_a < p_i \le b} \left\{ \pi\left(\frac x{p_i}\right) - (i-1) \right\}$$ counting semiprimes made up from primes in a certain range. The analogue would be

\begin{eqnarray*}
\Phi_2(n, a) &=& \underset{p_a < p_i \le p_j \le \frac n{p_i}}{\sum\sum} p_i p_j \\
&=& \sum_{p_a < p_i \le b} p_i \left( S\left(\frac n{p_i}\right) - S(p_i - 1) \right) \\
&=& \sum_{p_a < p_i \le b} p_i \left( S\left(\frac n{p_i}\right) - S(p_i) + 1 \right) \\
&=& \sum_{p_a < p_i \le b} p_i - \sum_{p_a < p_i \le b} p_i S(p_i) + \sum_{p_a < p_i \le b} p_i S\left(\frac n{p_i}\right) \\
&=& S(b) - a - \sum_{p_a < p_i \le b} p_i S(p_i) + \sum_{p_a < p_i \le b} p_i S\left(\frac n{p_i}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}